# AWS DMS to replicate transactional data to data warehouse on an ongoing basis

Tags: mysql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-dms

I'm hoping someone can tell me if I'm absolutely crazy before I go too far down this path. I have an application with MySQL as the backend. I needed to create more robust reporting and i opted to build a data warehouse in pgsql. The challenge is I don't want the DW to be just updated once or twice a day. I'd like it to be near real time (some lag is expected and not a problem).

I looked at AWS glue and a few other options and finally settled on DMS as a method of replicating the data from the MySQL source to the pgsql target db for staging. I then set up trigger functions that will basically manipulate the inserted/updated data in the pgsql db, landing it in the data warehouse. The application is also connected to the DW and can pull reports and dashboard metrics from the DW as needed.

I've built a proof of concept and it seems to work, but it's really only me hitting the application at the moment, so I'm not sure if it will hold up if I were to proceed with this idea and put it in production.

I currently have a dms.t2.small replication instance (engine version 2.4.4) running at about 15-20% CPU utilization. I don't have it configured for Multi AZ currently.

I'm seeing combined CDCLatencyTarget/CDCLatencySource values averaging about 9 seconds. I think if that holds true it wouldn't be unbearable, although the less time the better. I'd say if it gets up over a minute we may start to see complaints.

I know that DMS is more meant for migrations, so I'd like to know if I'm just doing this in a really stupid way, or if this is a more or less valid use case? Are there issues with DMS that I am unaware of that will cause me to later regret this decision?

Also, I'd love any ideas you have for how I can put safeguards in place to ensure that source and target stay synced or if they don't that I'm made aware of it, or something that would allow it to self-heal.

[image]

Comment: How big is your current MySql instance? How much data you have?

Comment: the dev instance where it's running right now is a t2.small, and the DB has about .2 GB of data on it. The prod instance where it will be running is a t2.medium with .5 GB of data on the transactional database.

Comment: also worthy of noting. We're in the process of a major application overhaul, and without going into too much detail, we have essentially 3 DMS continuous replication tasks running off the one DMS replication instance, replicating data across a few different environments. This will all go away once we push to production and then there will only be the one task i'm referencing in this question. But this is probably having some unknown (to me) impact on the current replication instance.